# How do you retrieve the Comments value from an RDOAddressEntry object?

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

I've written the following code below that loops round the Distribution List members and get the Comments value from each Address Entry member.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rdoDistList.MemberCount; ++i)
{
    RDOAddressEntry rdoAddressEntry = rdoDistList.GetMember(i);

    // This returns null
    string comments = rdoAddressEntry.Comments;

    rdoAddressEntry.Comments = "TESTING";
    rdoAddressEntry.Save();

    // This also returns null
    comments = rdoAddressEntry.Comments;

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rdoAddressEntry);
}
```

The problem is I can save the Comments value in an RDOAddressEntry object. But I can't retrieve it.

It's strange as I can retrieve the EntryID, Name and SMTPAddress values from an RDOAddressEntry object. But just can't retrieve the Comments value.

How can I retrieve the Comments value from an RDOAddressEntry object?

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the Redemption developer directly at http://dimastr.com/redemption/contact.htm instead.

Comment: Eugene, I am perfectly capable of answering the question here, especially if the question was tagged as "outlook-redemption". This is true of SO and other forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RDOAddressEntry.Fields[] to retrieve the PR_COMMENT property (0x3004001F).

Comment: I've just tried it using the Field property and that to returns null.

Comment: Can you see the comments in OutlookSpy? Click IAddrBook | OpenRootContainer and drill down to that GAL entry.

Comment: Can I confirm the OutlookSpy steps. 1/ Open the DL and click the IAddrBook button in the OutlookSpy tab. 2/ Click the OpenRootContainer button to display the IABContainer window. The displayed IABContainer window has the following tabs: GetProps, GeHierarchyTable, GetContentsTable, PR_CREATE_TEMPLATES, OpenEntry. I couldn't see the GAL entry in any of the tabs.

Comment: I've also tried it by 1/ Open the DL member (to display a Contact window) and click the IAddrBook button in the OutlookSpy tab. 2/ Click the OpenRootContainer button to display the IABContainer window. The displayed IABContainer window has the following tabs: GetProps, GeHierarchyTable, GetContentsTable, PR_CREATE_TEMPLATES, OpenEntry. I couldn't see the GAL entry in any of the tabs.

Comment: In the ABContainer window, go to the GetHieirachyTable tab and open the "Global Address List" container. Then go to the GetContentsTable tab and open the particular GAL entry. You can also open the entry if it is a recipient of a message - click IMessage, go to the GetRecipientTable tab, double click on the recipient.

Comment: The Contact / Address Entry isn't listed unfortunately as it lives in a sub folder under a Public Folder (and not in the GAL). I'm going to go with Plan B and use the GetContact method to get the member as a Contact (as most of the members are contacts) as I can get the Comments from a Contact member. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, RDOAddressEntry.GetContacrt is the way to go for the IPM.Contact based entries.